# Apply a set of Regex to multiple urls efficiently

Tags: regex, performance, url, bigdata, memory-optimization

I have a scenario where I have a set of urls (millions) and need to run a set of regexes (> 60k regex) to determine if a url match a regex then replace them with the replacement pattern.

```
   foreach(url in urls)
   {
           foreach(regex in regexes)
           {
                  newurl = Regex.Replace(url, matchpattern, replacement);
                  store newurl;
                  break;
           }
   }
```

The pattern could be like this:

Regex.Replace(url, "^http([s]?):/(/www.|/)en.wikipedia.org(.*)", "http$1://en.m.wikipedia.org$3");

I have a constraints on memory and run time. Currently, I only implement the like the above pseudocode code but the memory consumption is too high even with 6k regex (20Mb). I would like to know if there is a library that deal with this kind of problem already or if someone has suggestion of what kind of data structure I should build to optimize memory and runtime here.

Some more examples, on the left is match pattern, on the right is replacement pattern.

^http([s]?):/(/www.|/)youtube.com/watch\?(.*)    http$1://m.youtube.com/watch?$3
^http([s]?):/(/www.|/)facebook.com/(pages/.*|[^/]*$)    http$1://m.facebook.com/$3
^http([s]?):/(/www.|/)twitter.com/(.*)   http$1://mobile.twitter.com/$3
^http([s]?):/(/www.|/)yellowpages.com/(.*)   http$1://m.yellowpages.com/$3
^http([s]?):/(/www.|/)imdb.com/(title|name)/(.*)    http$1://m.imdb.com/$3/$4
^http([s]?):/(/www.|/)facebook.com/pages/(.*)   http$1://m.facebook.com/pages/$3
^http([s]?)://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q(\d+)$  http$1://m.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q$2
^http([s]?)://www.ebay.com.au/itm/([^/]*)/(\d+)$ http$1://m.ebay.com.au/itm/$2/$3
^http([s]?)://www.youtube.com/user/([^/?&]*)$ http$1://m.youtube.com/user/$2

Comment: Have you tried to do this only on the first url? Maybe you should do this operation chunk after chunk

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually do it chunk by chunk. But the problem is that I need to either store the set of Regexes in memory, which is huge, or I need to compile Regex on runtime and match them one after another, which is slow.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the actual regular expression search-replace patterns you are using? Ten randomly selected examples should be sufficient.

Comment: What language are you using? Some languages have support for pre-compiled Regex patterns so you can reuse them? Also it seems like a URL that matches a certain pattern may never be matched again. Can you stop running RegEx values on a given URL once one of the RegEx matches?

Comment: I am using C# but I can use C++ as well. In C#, I already use RegexOptions.Compiled. I already break in the internal loop once the Regex match.